# How do I create a Service Reference in C# in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-dynamics, service-reference

I use Visual Studio 2017 and have created a new C# program and a new codeunit in Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2015.

In my C# code, I want to call a method/function on the codeunit. But I cannot make a connection to the codeunit.

In NAV, I have added the codeunit as a public web service. When I take the NAV field "URL address to SOAP" ("http://myMachine.dk:7005/nav2015-udv/WS/myCompany/Codeunit/myCodeunit") and put it in a browser, I can use Wizdler to show the functions on the codeunit, when I enter an username and a password. And I can execute my function and get the result from NAV.

In Visual Studio, I activate "Add Service Reference" and enter the same text from "URL address to SOAP".

Then Visual Studio writes this:

"The service 'http://myMachine.dk:7005/nav2015-udv/WS/myCompany/Codeunit/myCodeunit/$metadata' at   requires a username and password" and when I enter it, it says:

"The service 'http://myMachine.dk:7005/nav2015-udv/WS/myCompany/Codeunit/myCodeunit' at   requires a username and password".

No matter what I write in username and password, it just keeps asking these two questions.

Please note that it seems to be missing a server name, since there does not stand anything after "at" in the form.

How do I make this work?

Comment: have you trued `http://username:password@url`

Comment: I have now. That didn't change anything.

Comment: It works perfectly if I enter "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL" witch is a free test VSDL. But my machine is in my companys network.

Comment: the test one works because it doesnt require authentication.. i set my local service to be anonymous access so that it can read it in

Comment: When I change from  "http://myMachine.dk:7005/..." to "http://123.123.123.123:7005/nav..." (using my correct IP-address) then it works! Case closed. Thanks for your time, BugFinder.

Comment: that implies something else is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

When I change from "myMachine.dk:7005..." to "123.123.123.123:7005/nav..." (using my correct IP-address) then it works! Case closed.